# Best practices: iOS 8 designing for autolayout with size classes and trait collections

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

We're trying to get a new version of our app using Autolayout, size classes and trait collections (since that's what Apple seems to be pushing for). We may have the luxury of having the deployment be on iOS 8 and up only. However, designing the UI using IB is driving me crazy. We need a video player view slide down on a swipe down gesture at runtime. The video view was setup using IB and the constraint setup with autolayout that holds it in place seems way too stubborn. The view cannot easily be moved around at runtime. Wondering how folks have faced similar issues and how they split their design.

1. Use storyboad for layout or have the storyboard load a xib ?
2. Use one xib for iPhone5, iPhone6 and 6+ and another for iPad or use traitcollections and sizeclasses with one xib ? (This is proving to be rather difficult to tune)
3. The constraint visual format seems more cryptic than regex, and I'm tired of unsatisfiable constraints in the logs.

What combination of xibs, storyboards, autolayout, traits and sizeclasses have folks gotten best results with ?

I am currently going with multiple storyboards and have view controllers load xibs in the storyboards (in the hope of reuse for the xib)

Comment: My approach is to use IB when UI is simple, otherwise sketch blank controllers and program ui manually.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this issue is to add properties to the constraints. When you want to slide the video view down then you do so by changing the constraints. Using this in conjunction with animations gives you the same smooth experience you would get by changing frames, etc.